# How to get all values from resultset?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, resultset

I'm trying to get all the values from the table and then assign them to a variable, there are only 2 options in the table so it can have 1 or 2 values, but when trying this it only gives back when first number (1) and the second (`$fila2 = $rs2[1];`) it says that is a Undefined offset

```
include('conexion.php');
$str_query2 = "SELECT gc_id FROM prod_grupocompl where pr_id='171' "; //  Variable que guarda la consulta a efectuar
$query2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$str_query2) or die (mysql_error()); // EjecuciÛn de la consulta y se guarda el resultado en $query
$rs2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
$fila = $rs2[0];
$fila2 = $rs2[1];
echo $fila;
echo $fila2;
```

Comment: You're only selecting one column from the database: `SELECT gc_id FROM`

Comment: hmm i see the problem, but i want the 2 values from that column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resultset will be returning two rows not two fields in one row.

To access the second row, I recommend a loop.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_NUM)){
    // now you can access the field value like this for each row...
    $fila=$row[0];  // do what you want with each value, echo or something.
}
```

p.s. `mysql_error()` is missing an `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try this:

```
$rs2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_NUM);
$fila = $rs2[0];
$fila2 = $rs2[1];
```

and if not try to see what is inside the array with:

```
print_r($rs2);
```

**UPDATE:** But as @Devon says: [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

> Fetch a result **row** as an associative, a numeric array, or both